# Ember JS: Sequential dependent async call to process

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, underscore.js

I am facing issue while submitting the request to the server. I need to send the data as after fetching other properties to process them. User can be new user or existing (with / without Company name).

When I am making call its not getting in sequence and final object does not have proper data and gets random data due to asynch process timing. For loop is getting completed early.

```
for (var i = 0; i<_uniqEditUsersList.length; i++){
    var _uniqEditUser = _uniqEditUsersList[i];
    var newUserid = $("[id='" + _uniqEditUser + "']")[0].value;
    console.log(_uniqEditUser + ' Data '+ newUserid);
    Service.searchUser(newUserid).then(function (userResult) {
        console.log("userResult: " + _.keys(userResult).length);
        console.log(_uniqEditUser2 + ' Data  '+ newUserid2);
        var currentCartId = self.get('cart').id;
        var userResult = userResult ? userResult : "";
        if (_.keys(userResult).length == 0) {
            CompanyName = "NEW_USER";
            var newData = {oldId: _uniqEditUser, newid: newUserid, CompanyName: CompanyName};
            dataMap[counter] = newData;
            if(counter == _uniqEditUsersList.length){
                self.set('processList', dataMap);
                self.processListFunction();
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
        } else {
            Service.getUsers(partnerListObj).then(function (result) {
                if (result.users.totalResults == "1") {
                    CompanyName = result.company;
                } else {
                    CompanyName = "NO_COMPANY"
                }
                var newData = {oldId: _uniqEditUser, newid: newUserid, CompanyName: CompanyName};
                dataMap[counter] = newData;
                if(counter == _uniqEditUsersList.length){
                    self.set('processList', dataMap);
                    self.processListFunction();
                }
                counter = counter + 1;
            }, function (err) {
                self.showErrorMessage(JSON.parse(err.responseText).message);
            });
        }
    }, function (err) {
        self.showErrorMessage(JSON.parse(err.responseText).message);
    });
}
```

How can I make calls dependent on each other and make for loop to process sequentially?

I tried lots of things but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the below might work for you. With some adjustments of course. Using reduce each promise will be dependent on the previous promise.

```
arrayOfTasksToResolveInOrder.reduce((promise, task) => {
  return promise.then((result) => {
      if (result.condition) {
        return task.fetch(result));
      } else {
        return task.someOtherFetch(result);
      }
    });
}, Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve());
```

The author of this post does a great job explaining this pattern [Promises Part II - Advanced promise patterns](https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2016/10/27/promises-part-ii-advanced-promise-patterns/)